# How can I access my scanner directly without going through System Preferences?

Tags: printing, scanning

Since my printer has scanning capabilities, the *Printers & Scanners* pane in *System Preferences* has the *"Scan"* tab available.
This is the only known place to start and scan one's document.

I am looking for a quicker way to access my printer scanning window.
searches for AppleScript and Automator solutions did not helped me.

Am I that bad a searching? The smallest hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Image Capture application can do this for you. Just connect your printer and launch the application. It comes with OS X.

[image]

Image borrowed from: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4505. You can also find instructions there under the heading *How to scan*.

Comment: Thank you, I might also type in _Spotlight Search_ the name of my printer wich will bring up the necessary interface with "scan" top-right of the window.

I now have the necessary info to search for a way to create an Automator/appleScript that 1-click-scan my document; maybe you can enlighten us with a nice resource for that..

Comment: @Buscar People's votes are their own. No-one should be compelled to upvote anything. If you disagree feel free to raise this on [meta].

Comment: @grgarside Common curtsey ! polite behavior that shows respect for other people, - something that you do because it is polite, kind, etc. Compelled definition, to force or drive, especially to a course of action

Answer (score 1):

Preview.app has some built-in scanning functionality you might try.

Open up the program, then go to `File / Import from <Your Scanner>...` if your computer finds any nearby scanners (attached via usb or over a network should both work).

Comment: although your solution is a totally valid one, i chose @Koen-van-Rhee 's answer as it is just a tad easier/faster to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I found a pretty easy way to access the scanner without going through System Preferences every time.

1. Find the printer via System Preferences->Printers & Scanners, and click Open Print Queue... This should open a new window for the printer. [image: Printers & Scanners window]
2. Right-click (or Cmd-click) on the title bar of the print queue window. Select the Printers option. This will open the hidden Printers folder in Finder. [image: Print Queue window] [image: Printers folder in Finder]
3. From here you should be able to see the app for the printer. Hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging the app to create a shortcut anywhere you want (I put mine in the Applications folder), and now you can use the shortcut to open the print queue window directly without going through System Preferences. Then just click the Scanner button to scan a document. [image: Print queue window Scanner button]

Hope this helps!